# When we use "too" in the middle of a sentence, what do we emphasize?

Tags: grammar

So I came across these sentences in "A History of English" by B. Strang:

> The lamb does not bleat in deliberate imitation of the sheep-community into which it is born; it bleats as its genetic blueprint lays down for it. The human baby has a genetic blueprint, **too**, relevant to language, a blueprint which enables it to become a learner of language.

I did some googling and found out, that we use "too" in the middle of a sentence with two comas when we want to emphasise something. My question is: What do we emphasize? Words that precede or follow the word "too"? And does context matter?

Comment: _Too_ in this context usually means _as well_ (as something already mentioned). The lamb has a genetic blueprint causing it to bleat; the baby also has a genetic blueprint, in this case enabling it to learn to speak.